# Reduction (sum) along arbitrary axes of a multidimensional array

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want to perform a sum reduction along arbitrary axes of a multidimensional matrix which may have arbitrary dimensions (e.g. axis 5 of a 10-dimensional array). The matrix is stored using the row-major format, i.e. as a `vector` together with the strides along each axis.

I know how to perform this reduction using nested loops (see example below), but doing this results in a hard-coded axis (the reduction is along axis 1 below) and an arbitrary number of dimensions (4 below). *How can I generalize this without using the nested loops?*

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  // shape, stride & data of the matrix

  size_t shape  [] = { 2, 3, 4, 5};
  size_t strides[] = {60,20, 5, 1};

  std::vector<double> data(2*3*4*5);

  for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < data.size() ; ++i ) data[i] = 1.;

  // shape, stride & data (zero-initialized) of the reduced matrix

  size_t rshape  [] = { 2, 4, 5};
  size_t rstrides[] = {20, 5, 1};

  std::vector<double> rdata(2*4*5, 0.0);

  // compute reduction

  for ( size_t a = 0 ; a < shape[0] ; ++a )
    for ( size_t c = 0 ; c < shape[2] ; ++c )
      for ( size_t d = 0 ; d < shape[3] ; ++d )
        for ( size_t b = 0 ; b < shape[1] ; ++b )
          rdata[ a*rstrides[0]                 + c*rstrides[1] + d*rstrides[2] ] += \
          data [ a*strides [0] + b*strides [1] + c*strides [2] + d*strides [3] ];

  // print resulting reduced matrix

  for ( size_t a = 0 ; a < rshape[0] ; ++a )
    for ( size_t b = 0 ; b < rshape[1] ; ++b )
      for ( size_t c = 0 ; c < rshape[2] ; ++c )
        std::cout << "(" << a << "," << b << "," << c << ") " << \
        rdata[ a*rstrides[0] + b*rstrides[1] + c*rstrides[2] ] << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

---

Note: I want to avoid 'decompressing' and 'compressing' a counter. By this I mean that I could, in pseudo-code, do:

```
for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < data.size() ; ++i ) 
{
  i -> {a,b,c,d}

  discard "b" (axis 1) -> {a,c,d}

  rdata(a,c,d) += data(a,b,c,d)
}
```

Comment: What does (de)compressing a counter look like?

Comment: @Useless I've added a pseudo-code of what I mean with (de)compressing a counter.

Comment: @TomdeGeus Why is stride value 60 being dropped and not 20? Is that a typo or am I misunderstanding the algorithm?

Comment: Oh, so you don't want to do a linear scan of the source converting the flat index into n-dimensional coordinates, right? But isn't that likely to be most efficient?

Comment: @Darhuuk `rstrides` contains the strides of the reduced array. As its shape is `{2,4,5}` its stride should be `{rshape[1]*rshape[0], rshape[0], 1} == {20, 5, 1}`. I've added comments to emphasize this point.

Comment: @Useless There must be a more cleaver way... What I call 'decompressing the index' involves still quite some modulo's. I would love to be precise which way would be most efficient, but I'm yet to find another way. In the meantime I could try to time the nested loops vs. the decompression.

Comment: You can probably do something nifty with an iterable slice proxy object, but it seems like a lot of work to set up in isolation. It feels more like part of a general matrix library.

Comment: @TomdeGeus Ah, of course, I don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how efficient this code is, but in my opinion, it is sure to be precise.

#### What's going on?

A little on `adjusted_strides`:

For `axis_count = 4`, `adjusted_strides` has size `5`, where:

```
 adjusted_strides[0] = shape[0]*shape[1]*shape[2]*shape[3];
 adjusted_strides[1] = shape[1]*shape[2]*shape[3];
 adjusted_strides[2] = shape[2]*shape[3];
 adjusted_strides[3] = shape[3];
 adjusted_strides[4] = 1;
```

Let's take the example where the number of dimensions is `4` and the shape of the multidimensional array (`A`) is `n0, n1, n2, n3`.

When we need to transform this array into another multidimensional array (`B`) of shape: `n0, n2, n3` (compressing `axis = 1 (0-based)`), then, we try to proceed as follows:

For each index of `A` we try to find its position in `B`.
Let `A[i][j][k][l]` be any element in `A`. Its position in `flat_A` will be `A[i*n1*n2*n3 + j*n2*n3 + k*n3 + l]`

**`idx = i*n1*n2*n3 + j*n2*n3 + k*n3 + l;`**

In the compressed array `B`, this element will be a part of (or added to), `B[i][k][l]`. In `flat_B` the index is **`new_idx = i*n2*n3 + k*n3 + l;`**.

**How do we form `new_idx` from `idx`?**

1. All the axes before the compressed axis have the shape of the compressed axis as a part of their product. In our example we had to remove axis `1`, so all the axes which were before the 1st axis (only one here: the `0th axis`) represented by `i`), have `n1` as a part of product (`i*n1*n2*n3`).
2. All the axes after the compressed axis remain unaffected.
3. Finally, we need to do two things:

   1. Isolate the indices of the axes before the index of the axis to be compressed and remove the shape of this axis:

      *Integer division*: `idx / (n1*n2*n3);` (`== idx / adjusted_strides[1]`).

      We are left with just `i`, which can be readjusted according to the new shape (by multiplying with `n2*n3`): we get

      `i*n2*n3` (`== i * adjusted_strides[2]`).
   2. We isolate the axes after the compressed axis, which are unaffected by its shape.

      `idx % (n2*n3)` (`== idx % adjusted_strides[2]`)

      which gives us `k*n3 + l`.
   3. Adding the results of step *i.* and *ii.* results in:

      `computed_idx = i*n2*n3 + k*n3 + l;`

      Which is the same as `new_idx`. So, our transformation was correct :).

#### Code:

Note: `ni` refers to `new_idx`.

```
  size_t cmp_axis = 1, axis_count = sizeof shape/ sizeof *shape;
  std::vector<size_t> adjusted_strides;
  //adjusted strides is basically same as strides
  //only difference being that the first element is the 
  //total number of elements in the n dim array.

  //The only reason to introduce this array was
  //so that I don't have to write any if-elses
  adjusted_strides.push_back(shape[0]*strides[0]);
  adjusted_strides.insert(adjusted_strides.end(), strides, strides + axis_count);
  for(size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i) {
    size_t ni = i/adjusted_strides[cmp_axis]*adjusted_strides[cmp_axis+1] + i%adjusted_strides[cmp_axis+1];
    rdata[ni] += data[i];
  }
```

#### Output (axis = 1)

```
(0,0,0) 3
(0,0,1) 3
(0,0,2) 3
(0,0,3) 3
(0,0,4) 3
(0,1,0) 3
(0,1,1) 3
(0,1,2) 3
(0,1,3) 3
(0,1,4) 3
(0,2,0) 3
(0,2,1) 3
(0,2,2) 3
(0,2,3) 3
(0,2,4) 3
(0,3,0) 3
(0,3,1) 3
(0,3,2) 3
...
```

Tested [here](https://ideone.com/bjC1NG).

For further reading, refer to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order#Address_calculation_in_general).

Comment: That's very clever, exactly where I'm looking for. I think I understand what is being done, but for future reference I do think that the post would benefit from an explanation of `ni`.

Comment: @TomdeGeus added explanation. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  // shape, stride & data of the matrix
  size_t shape  [] = {  2, 3, 4, 5};
  size_t strides[] = {60, 20, 5, 1};
  std::vector<double> data(2 * 3 * 4 * 5);

  size_t rshape  [] = { 2, 4, 5};
  size_t rstrides[] = {3, 5, 1};
  std::vector<double> rdata(2 * 4 * 5, 0.0);

  const unsigned int NDIM = 4;
  unsigned int axis = 1;

  for (size_t i = 0 ; i < data.size() ; ++i) data[i] = 1;

  // How many elements to advance after each reduction
  size_t step_axis = strides[NDIM - 1];
  if (axis == NDIM - 1)
  {
      step_axis = strides[NDIM - 2];
  }
  // Position of the first element of the current reduction
  size_t offset_base = 0;
  size_t offset = 0;
  size_t s = 0;
  for (auto &v : rdata)
  {
      // Current reduced element
      size_t offset_i = offset;
      for (unsigned int i = 0; i < shape[axis]; i++)
      {
          // Reduce
          v += *(data.data() + offset_i);
          // Advance to next element
          offset_i += strides[axis];
      }
      s = (s + 1) % strides[axis];
      if (s == 0)
      {
          offset_base += strides[axis - 1];
          offset = offset_base;
      }
      else
      {
          offset += step_axis;
      }
  }

  // Print
  for ( size_t a = 0 ; a < rshape[0] ; ++a )
    for ( size_t b = 0 ; b < rshape[1] ; ++b )
      for ( size_t c = 0 ; c < rshape[2] ; ++c )
        std::cout << "(" << a << "," << b << "," << c << ") " << \
        rdata[ a*rstrides[0] + b*rstrides[1] + c*rstrides[2] ] << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
(0,0,0) 3
(0,0,1) 3
(0,0,2) 3
(0,0,3) 3
(0,0,4) 3
(0,1,0) 3
(0,1,1) 3
(0,1,2) 3
(0,1,3) 3
(0,1,4) 3
(0,2,0) 3
(0,2,1) 3
(0,2,2) 3
// ...
```

Setting `axis = 3` yields:

```
(0,0,0) 5
(0,0,1) 5
(0,0,2) 5
(0,0,3) 5
(0,0,4) 5
(0,1,0) 5
(0,1,1) 5
(0,1,2) 5
(0,1,3) 5
(0,1,4) 5
(0,2,0) 5
(0,2,1) 5
(0,2,2) 5
(0,2,3) 5
// ...
```

Comment: I found a way how to break it ;) ([see example](https://ideone.com/0B6VC6)). However, I don't understand why it is broken....

Comment: @TomdeGeus Interestingly, there was a minor error from your side (using `MAX_DIM` instead of `m_ndim`) and a more significant one from mine (correctly offset computation). I fixed the answer, and the fixed code is [here](https://ideone.com/dlwj3K). In any case, even though the complexity is equivalent (iterating once through the first whole tensor), the other answer should be significantly better, cache-wise.

Comment: Thanks for the fix! In fact, I expected that in my off-site implementation `MAX_DIM` and `m_ndim` are equivalent, as I fill the strides until `MAX_DIM`. But this is not so important I guess. Indeed I go with the other implementation, but thanks a lot!